# Spring4 $ Tiles3 integration: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, servlets, configuration, spring-4, tiles-3

I am a newbie to Spring, but until know I havent meet any serious problem.

I would like to use some templeate mechanism with spring, so I've pick up Apache Tiles.
I thought that it will be the easiest. But I struggle with it for almost 2 days now.

I have problem wile configuring Spring4 with Apache Tiles3
Here is my configuration:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;

//import com.derp.common.wicketView.HomePage;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.derp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES = "services.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON = "common.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS = "cms.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS)
                });
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/tiles.xml" });
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.ALL)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .favorPathExtension(true); // default is true. just for clarity
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/js/*");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/*").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/img/*");
    }
}
```

and:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);     
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
}
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="defaultTemplate" template="/WEB-INF/layout/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/layout/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

controller:

```
package com.derp.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView mainPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
```

Can anyone could tell what do I miss here???

Answer (score 0):

I think you must define a new definition called "home" which extend the template "defaultTemplate" like that :

```
<!-- Home page -->
<definition name="home" extends="defaultTemplate" />
```

And return a String value in your controller like that:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mainPage() {
        return "home";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for You reply. Unfortunately I can't check Your solution, cause I gave up on Apache Tiles3. I've moved to working solution (Thymeleaf);